как сделать так, чтобы отображались маршруты: пеший, автомобильный, общественный транспорт
как сделать так, чтобы можно было выбрать и отображались маршруты: пеший, автомобильный, общественный транспорт.
В документации нашел только информацию о:
стандартный - легковой автомобиль;
грузовик;
мотоцикл.
А мне нужно для:
пеший, автомобильный, общественный транспорт

Уточните, пожалуйста, вы имеете в виду сервис JavaScript API или MapKit?
2024-11-08 12:24:12, Lion Style <>:

как сделать так, чтобы можно было выбрать и отображались маршруты: пеший, автомобильный, общественный транспорт.
В документации нашел только информацию о:
стандартный - легковой автомобиль;
грузовик;
мотоцикл.
А мне нужно для:
пеший, автомобильный, общественный транспорт

